# ¿Como llenar una caja de pixeles?

Tags: html, css

Tengo una caja, pero a esta caja la quiero llenar de pixeles, como la podria llenar?[image: Llenar de pixeles]

El cuadro negro que se ve en la parte superior izquierda quiero que se repita en todos los demas pixeles de la caja

Todo esta hecho por HTML y CSS

```
HTML

<div class="cuadrado">  
<div class="pixel"></div>
</div>
-------------------
CSS

.cuadrado{
    position: absolute;
    left: 200px;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 1000px;
    background: #FFF;
    
}

.pixel{
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    border: 1px solid black;

}
------------------
```

Muchas gracias por leer.

Comment: Que es la caja? Es un canvas?

Comment: Es un <div> en HTML

Comment: no entiendo que quieres lograr pero para hacer eso debes usar javascript, se me ocurre. Habria que generar 1 millon de divs? una locura. Si en lugar de un div usases un png negro de 1pixel x 1pixel seria sencillo y solo lo harias con css. Explica que quieres hacer y tal vez te podamos ayudar

Comment: Siii, tambien lo pense, 1 millon de divs de muchisimo, y tu idea es la respuesta, como podria poner un png y reproducirlo 1 millon de veces con CSS?
Por favor

Comment: Como complemente al comentario de @HernánGarcia simplemente crea una imagen de 1px por 1px negro, a tu div agregale un tamaño y alto y luego aplicale un background-image, al no ser tan grande la imagen lo que pasara es que se comenzara a repetir hasta llenar por completo el div pixel a pixel, que es lo que mide la imagen

Comment: Como @HernánGarcia fue el que planteo la idea dejare mi comentario y esperare a que el la agregue como respuesta para que puedas votarla como acertada

Comment: Creo que para lo que pretendes, lo mejor es que te estudies la etiqueta CANVAS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ahi tienes el ejemplo aunque yo no puse una imagen de 1 pixel cuadrado, solo tienes que reemplazar la imagen con la ruta de tu imagen, por otra parte, si pones una imagen de color solido sea del tamaño que sea va a quedar todo el div del mismo color, para eso solo ponle un background negro y ya.

```css
.contenedor{
   width: 1000px;
   height: 1000px;
   background: url(https://placeimg.com/100/100/animals);
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">

   </div>
```